# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException Apache Commons api

Tags: java, apache, email

I am trying out the following code with Apache Commons email API, and it throws error in the context. Any helps?

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;

import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;


public class email {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws EmailException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("email@gmail.com", "password");
                    }
                  });
SimpleEmail se = new SimpleEmail();
se.addTo("email@gmail.com");
se.setFrom("email@gmail.com");
se.setSubject("Test email");
se.setMsg("Hi there");
se.send();

    }

}
```

It throws the following error. Where/what should I set to overcome this?  any help in this regard?

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.registry.samples.SimpleClient.doit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.registry.samples.SimpleClient.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How does your `doit` method look like? Is `javax.xml.registry.samples.SimpleClient` the same as the code you post?

Comment: all I have is this code? AM I missing something? whats the doit method? Can you help?

Comment: I suppose you are using the wrong class? How do you run your Java class? You should use `email` class, not `javax.xml.registry.samples.SimpleClient`. Please check your stack trace.

Comment: not sure where it is picking it from...But I seem to resolve this issue by changing Simpleemail to Email and got a new one 'Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `javax.mail` and **Apache Commons Email**. This code should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
{
    try
    {
        Email se = new SimpleEmail();

        se.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
        se.setSmtpPort(465);
        se.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("email@gmail.com", "password"));
        se.setSSLOnConnect(true);


        se.addTo("email@gmail.com");
        se.setFrom("email@gmail.com");
        se.setSubject("Test email");
        se.setMsg("Hi there");
        se.send();
    }
    catch(EmailException e) {
        System.out.println("Uh oh! It doesn't work!");
    }
}
```

**More info :**

[Apache Commons Email Userguide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html)